# SQL Server low cpu and read count, high duration when ran in parallel

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have two procedures being called from a web api (using async/ await), and the second one always takes around 2 seconds when both are run in parallel. If I run one at a time they are both extremely fast - any thoughts on what might be happening here?

Here is what the profiler shows:
[image]

And here is the second one when executed on its own it only takes a few ms:
[image]

Here is what the problematic procedure looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserAccessGetList]
(
  @AuthenticatedUserID INT ,
  @PageNumber INT ,
  @PageSize INT ,
  @UserName VARCHAR(255) ,
  @FirstName VARCHAR(255) ,
  @LastName VARCHAR(255) ,
  @CompanyID INT ,
  @UserStatusID INT
)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    DECLARE @CurrentCompany HIERARCHYID ,
        @UserTypeID INT ,
        @UserCompanyID INT ,
        @SingleUser BIT = 0

    -- Retrieve the UserTypeID and Company for the user passed in.
    SELECT  @UserTypeID = [userType].[UserTypeID] ,
            @UserCompanyID = [user].[CompanyID] ,
            @CurrentCompany = [OrganizationNode]
    FROM    [dbo].[User] [user]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserType] [userType] ON [user].[UserTypeID] = [userType].[UserTypeID]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Company] [company] ON [company].[CompanyID] = [user].[CompanyID]
    WHERE   [user].[UserID] = @AuthenticatedUserID

    -- Returns a result set that lists all the users the user passed in has access to.
    SELECT  [user].[UserID] ,
            [user].[CommissionRate] ,
            [user].[PayrollID] ,
            [user].[PhotoURL] ,
            [user].[UserName] ,
            [user].[PasswordHash] ,
            [user].[UserStatusID] ,
            [user].[ReceivesCommission] ,
            [company].[CompanyID] ,
            [company].[CompanyName] ,
            [company].[CompanyLegalName] ,
            [company].[ShortName] [CompanyShortName] ,
            [company].[CommissionRate] [CompanyCommissionRate] ,                        
            [user].[UserTypeID]
            INTO #users
    FROM    [dbo].[User] [user]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Company] [company] ON company.CompanyID = [user].CompanyID
    WHERE   ( ( @UserTypeID = 1 AND @SingleUser = 0 ) OR ( ( @SingleUser = 1 OR @UserTypeID <> 1 ) AND [user].[UserID] = @AuthenticatedUserID ) )
            AND [company].[OrganizationNode].IsDescendantOf(@CurrentCompany) = 1
            AND [company].[CompanyTypeID] = 1

    SELECT  COUNT(1)
    FROM    #users

    SELECT  COUNT(1)
    FROM    [#users] [user]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserStatus] [userStatus] ON [userStatus].[UserStatusID] = [user].[UserStatusID]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Contact] [contact] ON [contact].[ContactID] = [user].[UserID]
    WHERE   ( @UserName IS NULL OR [user].[UserName] LIKE '%' + @UserName + '%' )
            AND ( @FirstName IS NULL OR [contact].[FirstName] LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%' )
            AND ( @LastName IS NULL OR [contact].[LastName] LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%' )
            AND ( @CompanyID IS NULL OR [user].[CompanyID] = @CompanyID )
            AND ( @UserStatusID IS NULL OR [user].[UserStatusID] = @UserStatusID )

    SELECT  [user].[UserID] ,
            [user].[UserName] ,
            [contact].[FirstName] ,
            [contact].[LastName] ,
            [contact].[EmailAddress] ,
            [contact].[TelephoneCount] ,
            [contact].[Telephone] ,
            [contact].[EmailAddressCount] ,
            [contact].[EmailAddress] ,
            [contact].[Address1] ,
            [contact].[Address2] ,
            [contact].[City] ,
            [contact].[State] ,
            [contact].[ZipCode] ,
            [user].[CommissionRate] ,
            [user].[PhotoURL] ,
            [userStatus].[UserStatusID] ,
            [userStatus].[UserStatus] ,
            [user].[ReceivesCommission] ,
            --[user].[CreatedBy]
            --[user].[CreatedDateTime]
            [userType].[UserTypeID] ,
            [userType].[UserType] ,
            [user].[CompanyID] ,
            [user].[CompanyName] ,
            [user].[CompanyName] [CompanyLegalName],
            [user].[CompanyName] [CompanyShortName]
    FROM    [#users] [user]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserStatus] [userStatus] ON [userStatus].[UserStatusID] = [user].[UserStatusID]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserType] [userType] ON [user].[UserTypeID] = [userType].[UserTypeID]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[vwContact] [contact] ON [contact].[ContactID] = [user].[UserID]
    WHERE   ( @UserName IS NULL OR [user].[UserName] LIKE '%' + @UserName + '%' )
            AND ( @FirstName IS NULL OR [contact].[FirstName] LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%' )
            AND ( @LastName IS NULL OR [contact].[LastName] LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%' )
            AND ( @CompanyID IS NULL OR [user].[CompanyID] = @CompanyID )
            AND ( @UserStatusID IS NULL OR [user].[UserStatusID] = @UserStatusID )
    ORDER BY [contact].[LastName] ,
            [contact].[FirstName] ,
            [user].[CompanyName]
            OFFSET ( @PageNumber - 1 ) * @PageSize ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
END
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is is called blocking. Share your store procedure code

Comment: There is no blocking, if you take a look at the "end time" you will notice the first one completes in a few ms, yet it takes another 2 seconds for the second procedure to complete, but in only takes 100 ms on its own.

Comment: Will you share code or not? Install `sp_whoisactive` and play with it.

Comment: I can share them, although the two procedures are a bit long. Here is what I discovered: I have pagination in both of them OFFSET ( PageNumber - 1 ) * PageSize ROWS FETCH NEXT PageSize ROWS ONLY, and when I replace the PageSize variable with an actual value say 10 for instance, I no longer see the performace issue - does this make sense at all that it would have this kind of an impact?

Comment: Maybe parameter sniffing. Try adding `option (OPTIMIZE FOR (@PageSize UNKNOWN,@PageNumber UNKNOWN))` as last clause in query

Comment: It behaves the same, the number of reads also went to 100k - I pasted the code in case you see something that may be wrong - the #users temp table has 4000 records.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by that, when both procedures execute this one takes 2 seconds, but the first one takes 100 ms, however if I just run the one I pasted above, it takes 100 ms as well. Both get executed with the same PageNumber: 1 and Pagesize: 10. If I replace the variable with a number then they are both fast. I must be missing something somewhere.